# How to focus on input box when page loads?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I am trying to focus on the first text box, or input box, on my page when my page first loads. So I would like a blinking cursor to show up in the first text box when the page loads. I have googled numerous solutions that all resulted in the same: use .focus() agreement. I have tried but still doesn't work.

This is in my init function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                $('#TranslationTextBox:first').focus();
                $(".parametersNumericbox:first").focus();
            });

            $(".parametersNumericbox").focus(function () {
                var input = $(this);
                setTimeout(function () {
                    input.select();
                });
            });
```

Only when I tab several times does it take me to the first textbox.

EDIT: html code (using Kendo UI):

```
 <td id="TranslationTextBox">
                            @(Html.Kendo().NumericTextBoxFor<double>(model => model.Translation).Format("#").Decimals(0).Min(0)
                                  .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "parametersNumericbox" })
                                  .Events(e => e
                                      .Change("TranslationTextBoxChanged")
                                      ))
                        </td>
```

The problem I am currently having is the focus appears to go to the buttons before the textfield on the page for some reason.

Comment: You're trying to focus on multiple objects on `ready()`.  Also it's hard to tell without seeing what you've got for HTML code.

Comment: Well it should be the same thing really. The same textfield.

Comment: Also isn't the second bit of code, the onfocus callback that selects itself unnecessary?

Comment: EDIT: see edit for html code using Kendo

Comment: You probably want something like `$(".parametersNumericbox:first input").focus();` to specify textbox within the **first** td.

Comment: Your first `.focus()` is trying to set focus to the td element, not to an element inside the td.

Comment: I tried this: $(".parametersNumericbox:first input").focus(); but if I tab, the tab goes to the first button on the page and not the textfield. There is no blinking cursor until I reach the first input box when is the 3rd element on the page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Javascript, sure, but you can also use HTML:

```
<input type="text" autofocus>
```

In jQuery you could do:

```
$("input, textarea, select").filter(":first").focus();
```

A problem with your code seems to be that you are focussing several items. When you do that the item that was last focussed will get the focus.